# Submit graphql mutation containing nested array of object playload with "aws-amplify"

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-amplify

I trying to submit below payload (nested array of objects) using [aws-amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/):

```
{
  "data": [
    { "name": "alpha", "description": "lorem" },
    { "name": "bravo", "description": "ipsum" },
  ]
}
```

This solution (source code is TypeScript):

```js
import AWSAmplifyAPI, { graphqlOperation } from "@aws-amplify/api";


const rawGraphQLRequest: string = `
  mutation ($data: [registerMultipleItemsInput]!) {
    registerMultipleItems(data: [$data])
  }`;

type Item = {
  name: string;
  description: string;
}

async function registerMultipleItems(items: Array<Item>): Promise<void> {
  await AWSAmplifyAPI.graphql(graphqlOperation(rawGraphQLRequest, { data: items }));
}
```

causes unclear error:

```
Validation error of type VariableTypeMismatch: Variable type '[registerMultipleItemsInput]!' doesn't match expected 
type 'registerMultipleItemsInput' @ 'registerMultipleItems'";
```

Is backend, the scheme defined as:

```
registerMultipleItems(data: [registerMultipleItemsInput]!): [String]!
    @aws_cognito_user_pools

input registerMultipleItemsInput{
  name: String!
  description: String!
}
```

I tried to add `registerMultipleItemsInput` definition to `rawGraphQLRequest`:

```js
const rawGraphQLRequest: string = `

  input registerMultipleItemsInput {
    name: String!
    description: String!
  }

  mutation ($data: [registerMultipleItemsInput]!) {
    registerMultipleItems(data: [$data])
  }`;
```

Above error left, and additional error occurred:

```
Validation error of type NonExecutableDefinition: The registerMultipleItemsInput definition is not executable.
```

What the correct syntax for `{ "data": <Array>` } payload?

P. S. I hope I don't need to define `registerMultipleItemsInput` in `rawGraphQLRequest`, because `registerMultipleItemsInput` already has been defined in backend and defining it again in frontend is some kind of hardcoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your first solution is correct except for:

```
mutation ($data: [registerMultipleItemsInput]!) {
    registerMultipleItems(data: [$data]) // <-------- incorrect
}`;
```

`$data` already contains an array of `registerMultipleItemsInput` but you've wrapped it in another array which is incorrect, it must be:

```
mutation ($data: [registerMultipleItemsInput]!) {
    registerMultipleItems(data: $data) // <-------- correct
}`;
```